# Phonegap application position fixed menu

Tags: android, css, cordova

I'm working on a mobile application and I have a fixed footer menu.

```
<div id='footer'> 
   <ul class='menu'>
      <li>menu1</li>
       <li>menu2</li>
    </ul>   
</div>
   #footer { height:99px; background:url(../images/black2.png)repeat-x; border-top: 1px solid black; position:fixed;bottom:0;width:100%;}
    .menu { max-width:640px; margin:auto; }
```

I tested it on an Android device. The problem is that when I change the device orientation the menu ul's margin:auto doesn't work until I click on another menu item. 
Thank you!

**I resolved this by changing CSS.**

```
#footer { height:99px; background:url(../images/black2.png)repeat-x; border-top: 1px solid black; position:fixed;bottom:0;width:100%; text-align:center;}    
.menu {width:100%; max-width:640px; display:inline-block; }
```

Comment: have you write any thing on orientation change event??

Comment: I've not. Everything else is as it should be. Only that fixed footer is a problem. If I remove position fixed it works. But I need it was fixed. what should I do?  Thank you :)

Comment: Great..well done for resolved this issue by ownself.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer"> 
<ul>
  <li>menu1</li>
  <li>menu2</li>
</ul>   
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer { background: black; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; text-align: center; }    
.footer ul { color: white; width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; display: block; list-style: none; }
.footer ul li { padding: .25em; display: block; }
```

On top of that I'd tell you to checkout the "fixed-fixed" plugin from the Filament Group (that aids in mobile fixed positioning since all phones/ tablets don't support it):
https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-fixed

On top of top of that, I'd recommend their entire workflow for building for mobile:
https://github.com/filamentgroup/Southstreet/